# Line breaks or page formatting in TuxGuitar

Tags: tablature, mac, tuxguitar

I'm trying to write bass tabs in TuxGuitar, but want to format the print layout. I can't figure out how to set the number of measures per line or how to add a line break in the tabs. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print formatting appears to be unsupported. [Wayne Gabree's tutorial](http://waynegabree.com/theory/TuxGuitar%20Tutorial.pdf) makes no mention of it, a [question similar to yours](https://www.banjohangout.org/archive/303197) received no answers, and a [related bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/tuxguitar/bugs/76/) also suggests there is no such support.

From the bug report:

> Luis - 2018-07-28: Style.stringSpacing works very well for the screen but not for printing the tab. Could you help me in discovering which setting I should alter to have the same effect on printing?

> Julian Casadesus - 2018-07-28: Sorry, this setting isn't available for printing. the only choice is modifying printer notes font size at the settings window

Short of exporting to another format that supports print settings, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for grouping these sources together here. I think it would be a nice feature as it is the only thing missing for me right now.
My workaround now is to set the print preview to just those measures needed per row and combine them in an image editing program. That works for small pieces, but isn't doable for a whole song.